# How to invoke a Springboot Rest Service from ADF 12c

Tags: rest, web-services, oracle-adf

I have a Rest webservice to invoke from Oracle ADF. The service simply returns a success flag and a message. No need to have a Data Control for this.
Is there a rest client that I can use to invoke this rest service?

Answer (score 0):

Other than 'REST Data Control, there is not any in-built in REST client available
in 'Oracle ADF'. Since 'Oracle ADF' is J2EE framework, you can any other java library like Jersey to invoke the RESTful service.

Answer (score 0):

Rest client create http request GET, PUT, POST etc... to restful webservice.
You can use

> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

To call restFul API

Other way is using  `postman`